# How do I configure Nginx Proxy Manager to proxy an OnlyOffice Document Server Docker container?

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl, proxy, onlyoffice

I have spent an embarrassing amount of time trying to resolve this issue. I am running Nginx Proxy Manager and have not had any problems with it until around the start of October. Until then I was using the default settings in Nginx Proxy Manager proxied to OnlyOffice. I am using a wildcard SSL cert from Let's Encrypt with DNS challenge through DigitalOcean.

This is my docker-compose.yml for the OnlyOffice Document Server:

```yaml
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# OnlyOffice
#
# use port 80 with Nginx Proxy Manager
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
version: "3"
services:
  onlyoffice:
    container_name: onlyoffice
    domainname: mydomain.tdl
    environment:
      - JWT_ENABLED=true
      - JWT_SECRET=anAmazingSecretThatWillBlowYourMind
      - WOPI_ENABLED=true
    hostname: onlyoffice
    image: onlyoffice/documentserver
    networks:
      proxy_network:
        aliases:
          - onlyoffice
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./config/onlyoffice/app:/var/lib/onlyoffice
      - ./config/onlyoffice/data:/var/www/onlyoffice/Data
      - ./config/onlyoffice/fonts:/usr/share/fonts/truetype/custom
      - ./config/onlyoffice/log:/var/log/onlyoffice
      - ./config/onlyoffice/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql
      - ./config/onlyoffice/rabbitmq:/var/lib/rabbitmq
      - ./config/onlyoffice/redis:/var/lib/redis
networks:
  proxy_network:
    external: true
```

And this is my Nginx Proxy Manager docker-compose.yml file:

```yaml
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Nginx Proxy Manager
#
# use port 81 with Nginx Proxy Manager
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
version: "3"
services:
  nginxproxymanager:
    container_name: nginxproxymanager_app
    depends_on:
      - mariadb-aria
    domainname: mydomain.tdl
    environment:
      - DB_MYSQL_HOST=nginxproxymanager_db
      - DB_MYSQL_PORT=3306
      - DB_MYSQL_USER=nginxproxymanager_user
      - DB_MYSQL_PASSWORD=TheMostSecurePas5w0rd
      - DB_MYSQL_NAME=nginxproxymanager_db
      - DISABLE_IPV6=true
    hostname: nginxproxymanager_app
    image: jc21/nginx-proxy-manager
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - nginxproxymanager_app
      macvlan_network:
        aliases:
          - nginxproxymanager
        ipv4_address: www.xxx.yyy.zzz
      proxy_network:
        aliases:
          - nginxproxymanager
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./config/data:/data
      - ./config/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
  mariadb-aria:
    container_name: nginxproxymanager_db
    domainname: mydomain.tdl
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=EvenM0reSecurePas5w0rd
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=nginxproxymanager_db
      - MYSQL_USER=nginxproxymanager_user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=TheMostSecurePas5w0rd
    hostname: nginxproxymanager_db
    image: jc21/mariadb-aria
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - nginxproxymanager_db
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - /cache/nginxproxymanager/mariadb-aria:/var/lib/mysql
networks:
  default:
  macvlan_network:
    external: true
  proxy_network:
    external: true
```

This is the default Nginx Proxy Manager CONF file that is generated with the settings I have been using:

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------
# onlyoffice.mydomain.tdl
# ------------------------------------------------------------


server
{
  set $forward_scheme http;
  set $server "onlyoffice";
  set $port 80;

  listen 80;
  #listen [::]:80;

  listen 443 ssl http2;
  #listen [::]:443;


  server_name onlyoffice.mydomain.tdl;


  # Let's Encrypt SSL
  include conf.d/include/letsencrypt-acme-challenge.conf;
  include conf.d/include/ssl-ciphers.conf;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/npm-4/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/npm-4/privkey.pem;


  # Asset Caching
  include conf.d/include/assets.conf;


  # Block Exploits
  include conf.d/include/block-exploits.conf;


  # HSTS (ngx_http_headers_module is required) (63072000 seconds = 2 years)
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000;includeSubDomains; preload" always;


  # Force SSL
  include conf.d/include/force-ssl.conf;


  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;


  access_log /data/logs/proxy-host-44_access.log proxy;
  error_log /data/logs/proxy-host-44_error.log warn;


  location /
  {


    # HSTS (ngx_http_headers_module is required) (63072000 seconds = 2 years)
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000;includeSubDomains; preload" always;


    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;


    # Proxy!
    include conf.d/include/proxy.conf;
  }


  # Custom
  include /data/nginx/custom/server_proxy[.]conf;
}
```

If I remove the SSL cert from the Proxy Host entry for OnlyOffice in Nginx Proxy Manager it works as expected. I have watched Spaceinvader One's [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dEOfwKH2DHc) video among others on the topic and have not been able to resolve this issue. I have added every additional parameter I have come across, including the ones Spaceinvader One has in his example Nginx config in all combinations that I can think of.

I am including this screenshot of the error I am currently receiving when attempting to access the example editor in Google Chrome. I get this error, or the editor just does not load at all. I also experience these errors in other browsers as well.

[image: Screenshot of Error]

When attempting to use the OnlyOffice connector in NextCloud, it is unable to connect and displays this message:

[image: NextCloud OnlyOffice connector error]

I am hoping someone could point me in the right direction or offer assistance because I honestly have no idea where else to look and am on pages 4 and 5 of my Google searches looking for answers.

I switched from using the [SWAG container](https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/swag) by [linuxserver.io](https://www.linuxserver.io/) to Nginx Proxy Manager in January because I am not always around and it is a lot easier for me to talk someone through how to do something on the server when I am not around if it has a GUI.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After taking some time away from this problem I came back to it tonight. After updating all the containers involved I added the following lines to the Nginx Proxy Manager Custom locations field:

```
resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=30s;
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
```

And everything seems to be working as expected now.

[image]

Comment: You have literally saved my life, I've been with this problem for hours....
Could you explain me what this config does exactly?

Answer (score 0):

hey I tried the solution above but I was not successful, I had already given up, but today I went to configure qbitorrent in the Nginx proxy manager and I was not able to access it due to a redirection error. Then I found a configuration and managed to fix qbitorrent and to my surprise the same configuration worked for onlyoffice.
In custom locations you need to add

```
proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host   $http_host;
proxy_cookie_path  /                  "/; Secure";
```